# Unrecognized attribute 'sameSite'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive for Chrome version 80+

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, setcookie, httpcookie, samesite

I have a application runnig where the contents open in iframe which is treated as cross-site scenarios.

I'm aware of the latest chrome 80+ version update where all the cookies are set to **SameSite=Lax** by default. My application was working fine with older version of chrome and with below tag added in my web.config file

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" sameSite="None"/>
```

Now with this tag added, I get error **"Unrecognized attribute 'sameSite'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive"**.
Without the tag, my application loads but I'm not able to browse through contents since it opens in iframe.

As per the blog [here](https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie#step-2-fixing-cookie-errors-using-appropriate-attributes) , asks me to add SameSite=None; Secure tag , but adding tag itself errors out. Am I missing out anything ?

As a work-around I have disabled SameSite by default cookies from flag **chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies** and now it seems to work fine.
Is there a way I can achieve this by adding tag in web.config rather than explicitly doing client side changes. Why am I getting unrecognized error for sameSite attribute ?

Comment: "Why am I getting unrecognized error for sameSite attribute?" because that's what your application says. We don't know what's there and you didn't tell us. Try using an upper case letter e.g. `SameSite` instead of `sameSite`. Otherwise refer tothe documentation or the source code for your application.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have used SameSite , sameSite and also samesite. Same error. Yes I'm getting unrecognized attribute error and am curious to know why since the attribute seems right and used to work before.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research found a way to do it from code-behind

```
HttpCookie Cookie = new HttpCookie("Cookie")
{
   Value = "value to be stored,
   Secure = true,
   HttpOnly = true
};
```

This adds the cookie to context with http and secure flag as true.

The issue was due to the samesite was by default assigned as "Lax" after the recent chrome update. Since my website was opening in iframe the cookies were not being passed due to cross-site requests. Changing it to none resolved the issue.